# Going from a budo local server setup to deployment on google cloud app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, package.json, budo

I trying to deploy a website which works flawlessly on my local Budo server. I'm trying to deploy it to Google App Engine, but I don't have enough knowledge about node.js and package.json to specify the configurations to run my website on App Engine.

My app has the following scripts running in my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "budo main.js:dist/bundle.js --live --host localhost",
"watch": "watchify main.js -v --debug -o dist/bundle.js",
"prep": "yarn && mkdirp dist",
"build": "browserify main.js -o dist/bundle.js",
"lint": "eslint main.js --fix",
"deploy": "yarn build && uglifyjs dist/bundle.js -c -m -o dist/bundle.min.js"
},
```

I know the simple commands to deploy the server and the surrounding configurations of the Google Cloud Platform, but I don't know how to change my dependencies to work on the App Engine.

When I deploy the current setup I simply get 503 connection error.

So how do I port this to a setup that will work in production?

Comment: 503 is service unavailable, are you sure your server is up and running? Do you see any error when you do npm start?

Comment: I'm using Yarn, but my impression from the google documentation is that I shouldn't do this, for my server to run. I'll try this and get back.

Comment: Google app deploy automatically runs the start command when the files have been uploaded. I don't have to run it manually. Also the files are stored in a bucket and I don't have access to the directory directly, to do it manually.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? have encountered similar problem.
also no idea where the port number is configured in my example.